# What is the proper Pattern for my requirement using RegEx

Tags: regex, excel, vba

Can you please tell me what will be the proper pattern for my requirement.

I have a string and I want find the string between particular pattern. I have code I tried so far but unable to get the expected result.

**Input String**

`ssdfsfssXf1sddfsXfsdaf578ds0Xafds1dsfXdafspfsfsfsfds`

**Expected Result**

```
Xf1sddfsX

Xafds1dsfX
```

**Actual Result**

```
Xf1sddfsXfsdaf578ds0Xafds1dsfX
```

**VB Code**

```
Sub RegEx_Tester()

Dim objRegExp As RegExp
   Dim objMatch As Match
   Dim colMatches   As MatchCollection
   Dim RetStr As String
   ' Create a regular expression object.
   Set objRegExp = New RegExp

   'Set the pattern by using the Pattern property.

   objRegExp.Pattern = "X.*X"

   ' Set Case Insensitivity
   objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True

   'Set global applicability.
   MyString = "ssdfsfssdXf1sddfsXfsdaf578ds0Xafds1dsfXdafspfsfsfsfds"
   objRegExp.Global = True
   Set colMatches = objRegExp.Execute(MyString)  ' Execute search.

    For Each objMatch In colMatches   ' Iterate Matches collection.
            Debug.Print objMatch.Value 
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks In Advance !!

Comment: You want `X[^X]++X`. Your current pattern is greedy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Non-greedy(Lazy) way

Change :

```
X.*X
```

To:

```
X.*?X
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/yM8eU2/2)

---

OR better use

```
X[^X]*+X
```

[**Negated Character Classes/Sets**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

> Typing a caret after the opening square bracket negates the character class. The result is that the character class matches any character that is not in the character class.

with  [**Possessive Quantifiers**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)

> Possessive quantifiers are a way to prevent the regex engine from trying all permutations. This is primarily useful for performance reasons.

---

A worth reading post on [✽ Want to Be Lazy? Think Twice.](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#lazy_warning)

> However, a lazy quantifier has a cost: at each step inside the braces, the engine tries the lazy option first (match no character), then tries to match the next token (the closing brace), then has to backtrack.

See [✽ A Time for Greed, a Time for Laziness.](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#greedy_lazy)

> A reluctant (lazy) quantifier can make you feel safe in the knowing that you won't eat more characters than needed and overshoot your match

Comment: Excellent Man!! Thumbs Up!!

Comment: follow the link. You will get all the answers.

Comment: Thank you so much for prompt reply !! Waiting for minimum time to accept answer :)